# Can anyone find the number of Neurons and Kernal Size in the below given CNN model Code? I want to display each neuron inside the layer in a diagram

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to know the number of Neurons and Kernal Size in the below given CNN model Code.  I want to display each neuron inside the layer in a diagram to give a visual working of my model.

```
Input: Three Values as X,Y, Z    
    //layer:1
        model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation = 'relu', input_shape = x_train[0].shape)) 
        model.add(Dropout(0.1))  

        //layer:2 
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation = 'relu'))   model.add(Dropout(0.2))  model.add(Flatten())

        //layer:3
        model.add(Dense(64, activation= 'relu')) 
        model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 

        //layer:4
        model.add(Dense(3, activation= 'softmax'))

    Output: Three Values as X, Y, Z
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCVaQ.png)

Comment: Please **format** your code and use an appropriate language tag (this would seem to be Python, save for the `//`).

Comment: sorry, I am new here. Can you please help me regarding my query?

Comment: Formatting your code as required and providing additional information currently missing is a ~ 3-5 min procedure. If you are not willing to spend this time in order to improve *your* question, you should consider that you are maybe in the wrong community (why exactly should anyone spend *their* time with your question?)

Comment: I just edit it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conv2D(NUMBER_FILTERS,(SIZE_FILTER),...)

Dense(NUMBER_NEURONS,...)

Let me explain your code:

```
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation = 'relu', input_shape = x_train[0].shape))
```

16 refers number of filter, (2, 2) refers each filter size, relu is the activation function

`model.add(Flatten())` convert your tensor output into vector format, programmatically you may say 1D-array. We usually do this to feed our features extracted from the CNN layers to a fully connected layer.

```
model.add(Dense(64, activation= 'relu'))
```

It is fully connected layer, 64 is the neurons and relu is the activation function on each neuron

```
model.add(Dense(3, activation= 'softmax'))
```

This is your output layer. 3 depicts your number of outputs, and the softmax function will give you the predicted probabilities corresponds to each class.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to use a notation similar to keras. If that is correct, then I think your layers definition are as follows:

Conv2D(NUMBER_FILTERS,(SIZE_FILTER),...)

Dense(NUMBER_NEURONS,...)

So, as an example, you have 16 2x2 masks to train in the first layer, i.e. 64 neurons.

To build a visual representation of your CNN, I suggest to check this link:

http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html

However, if you want to analyze the complexity of your ANN, finding the number of parameters you need to train might be more representative than the number of neurons. The library that you use probably has a built-in function that does it for you.